# The function 'has' is not working on loaded data using jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using the function `has()` for checking if a `li` tag has `ul` inside. If a `ul` tag is in `li` I will add some CSS properties, My code works well when the `li` tags are created while rendering the page but when I use Ajax and `$.each()` for creating these `li` items the `has()` does not work.

The jquery code is:

```
$('.innerItems li ul li').has('ul').css({'background-image':'url(images/arrow.png)',
                                         'background-position':'2px center',
                                         'background-repeat':'no-repeat'});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `.find` instead, `.has` is just for test whether it has the `ul`.

```
$('.innerItems li ul li').find('ul').css({'background-image':'url(images/arrow.png)',
                                         'background-position':'2px center',
                                         'background-repeat':'no-repeat'});
```

***Edit:***
Seems you want this instead:

```
$('.innerItems li ul li:has(ul)').css({'background-image':'url(images/arrow.png)',
                                         'background-position':'2px center',
                                         'background-repeat':'no-repeat'});
```

Comment: If I use `find`, the css properties will apply to `ul` of `.innerItems li ul li` , But I want apply the css properties to `.innerItems li ul li`

Comment: @MajAfy If you mean that, your code should be ok, could your make a demo to show your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to write this line :

```
$('.innerItems li ul li').has('ul').css({'background-image':'url(images/arrow.png)',
                                     'background-position':'2px center',
                                     'background-repeat':'no-repeat'});
```

**BEFORE** your `$.each` which create `<li>` items.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to select the UL instead and then go back to the closest LI and apply styles. Seems more logical to me:

```
$('.innerItems li ul li ul').closest('li').css( //...
```

Alternative solution using `.find()`:

```
$('.innerItems li ul li').find('ul').closest('li').css( //...
```

But they will be essentially equal.